# utf8 encoding for emoji in R showing wrong result

Tags: r, emoji

I've a set of twitter emojis:

```
description       r.encoding    unicode     width
shootingstar    <f0><9f><8c><a0> U+1F320      16
wrappedgift     <f0><9f><8e><81> U+1F381      16
yellowheart     <f0><9f><92><9b> U+1F49B      16
femalesign      <e2><99><80>     U+2640       12
frowningface    <e2><98><b9>     U+2639       12
```

And a set of tweets:

```
[1] "Ring<f0><9f><9a><b4><e2><80><8d><e2><99><80><ef><b8><8f> Order today and have it within 3 days<e2><9d><a3><ef><b8><8f>\n"
[2] "Really I have been thinking <f0><9f><a4><94> about surfing <f0><9f><8f><84><e2><80><8d><e2><99><80><ef><b8><8f>"
```

When I'm trying to get name of emojis in these texts. using:

```
vec <- str_count(string, matchto)# string is the text, matchto is r.encodig
matches <- which(vec != 0)
```

in some cases it shows wrong result.
specifically for the emojis which are not in my emoji set.

for example

```
"femalesign" emoji is:<e2><99><80>
```

in both tweets, my codes shows "female sign" emoji, however when I checked the tweet, the user is actually using "woman biking" and "woman surfing" which are not in my emoji dataset

```
woman biking:  <f0><9f><9a><b4><e2><80><8d><e2><99><80><ef><b8><8f>
woman surfing: <f0><9f><8f><84><e2><80><8d><e2><99><80><ef><b8><8f>
```

So the output that I was expecting was :

```
NA
NA
```

May I know if there's a solution? is there a specific pattern which can help?

```
I was wondering if there's  a pattern /regex that can help in recognising
 whether this kind of sequence for example "<f0><9f><9a><b4><e2><80><8d> 
<e2><99><80> <ef><b8><8f>", belongs to an emoji , regardless which emoji is it
```

Because we have more than 2,000 emojis, and it'd be very time consuming to gather info of all emojis since I couldn't find a comprehensive file that includes emoji name and utf-8. Plus emojis frequently get updated.

Comment: `str_count` is returning *femalesign* because its encoding is a part of both the biking and surfing emojis: <f0><9f><9a><b4><e2><80><8d> **<e2><99><80>** <ef><b8><8f>.  

A possible solution would be to extract out the emojis from the tweets and look them up in your emoji dataframe for their corresponding name

Comment: The problem is that these are compound emojis that are rendered specially by certain platforms. The woman biking is really bicyclist (<f0><9f><9a><b4>) + zero-width joiner (<e2><80><8d>) + female sign (<e2><99><80>) + variation selector-16 (<ef><b8><8f>). See: https://emojipedia.org/woman-biking/

Comment: @James Yes,I'm ware of the reason for this issue, and looking for solution

Comment: @clmarquart, "A possible solution would be to extract out the emojis from the tweets" I'm already doing it, First I convert the text to UTF8 and extract emoji with str_count to get tweets with emoji. but results are not correct. Possibly because my set of emojis is not complete, and some emojis are missing, which I explained the reason in last paragraph of the main post. I was wondering if there's  a pattern /regex that can help in recognising whether  "<f0><9f><9a><b4><e2><80><8d><e2><99><80><ef><b8><8f>" belongs to an emoji

Comment: You need to write down all possible structures of emojis as regexs, the zero-width joiner may be used as a structure to prevent matching within a compound expression via look-ahead and look-behind.